# SharePoint 2010 get username for web application

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the current login user data from SharePoint 2010 to another web application. I am trying to use the javascript code to get the user and then pass it to the web application. I dont know where to start. My scenario is that I need to put a link on the SharePoint which would open a new form on a different web application and populate the user name value into it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can get the current user login name in Javascript:
[get-current-users-loginname-ecmascript-sharepoint-2010](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/05/18/get-current-users-loginname-ecmascript-sharepoint-2010/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var context = null;
var web = null;
var currentUser = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetUserLoginName, "sp.js");
function GetUserLoginName() {
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(this._currentUser);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
var today = new Date();
alert(' Name:' + this._currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login:' + this._currentUser.get_loginName());
}
function onFaiureMethod(sender, args) {
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. I had already tried this but this only gives me the name through the alert and provides a pop up. I need to copy the username and paste it into a form in another web application. I need to pass this username to different server.

Answer (score 1):

This code sometimes work well, sincerely I prefer use to SPServices.

with jquey:

```
var Username = $("#zz16_Menu").text();
alert(Username+" yname");
```

with only javascript:

```
var Username = document.getElementById("zz16_Menu").innerHTML ;
var end = Username.indexOf("<");
var nameOnly = Username.substring(8, end);
alert(nameOnly+" xname");
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPServices Jquery from CodePlex.](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Do the necessary steps:

1. Download the latest jquery.js from [SPServices Jquery.](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)
2. Upload the minnified js file to the style library of your site.
3. Add the script link `<script type="text/javascript" src="Path of the JS file"> </script>` to the master page.
4. Add the following code

   ```
   $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
       fieldName: "Name",
       debug: false
   });`
   ```